# how to use Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration?

Tags: asp.net-core

I find that The package:Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeGeneration has over 20,000,000 downloads in the nuget.but I can not find any doc.

how to use it?

any articles about it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### What does this package do

Basically, the package offers a single command to generate code:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator {name}
```

You can find the [source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/blob/490b73570adfa270b11f4d340a6d871e5137ab25/src/VS.Web.CG/CodeGenCommand.cs#L32-L60).

### How to use the package

We don't use the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration` **directly** unless we're creating a new command to generate code.

Because it is a command library for **generic purpose**, **concrete commands are defined in other packages**. For example, the `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller` command is defined in [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/tree/490b73570adfa270b11f4d340a6d871e5137ab25/src/VS.Web.CG.Mvc/Controller). And the command `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity` is also defined in the `CG.MVC` package.

Usually , since this package is a generic purpose library, you won't reference this package directly. Instead, You'll add the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`. Be aware the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package has a dependency on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc`, and the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc` depends on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration`:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
   | 
   |(depends on)
   |-----------> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc
                | 
                |(depends on)
                |-----------> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration
```

Be aware the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` is **automatically** added into your dependencies when you use Visual Studio to **scaffold** a controller/identity.

If you're using a VSCode/CLI, you need to **manually** add such a package reference. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#add-nuget-packages

Comment: How does one remove it from a project?

Comment: Can somebody explain why isn't this added only as desing-time-only dependency?

Answer (score 0):

What @itminus says. I think the reason it has so many downloads is from the clear error message when you try to use `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` without `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` NuGet.

As of 2021-08-27 it has `90,672,569 total downloads`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/

Example error:

> Building project ...
>
> Scaffolding failed.
>
> Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a
> NuGet package reference. To see more information, enable tracing by setting
> environment variable 'codegen_trace' = 1.