# aspnet-codegenerator: No code generators available, Even after adding Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Unable to generate scaffolding using **aspnet-codegenerator**, below is what I tried:

1. Created an ASP.Net RazorPages application using
   `dotnet new webapp`
2. Did a `dotnet build`
3. Installed dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator using

   `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.4`
4. Ran `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --help`

   It says: No code generators are available in this project.Add **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design** package to the project as a NuGet package reference.
5. Added the package mentioned in step 4 using

   `dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`

   Package added is:

   `<ItemGroup> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.4" /> </ItemGroup>`
6. Again ran: `dotnet build`

   Final-Step
7. Ran `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --help`

   **Again** it says: No code generators are available in this project.Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.

.NET Core installed version: 3.1.401

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Originally, I have those Code Generators available as expected.  However, after I have updated the .NET Core SDK as version 3.1.401, it is now reported that "No code generators are available in this project."

Comment: Many people encounter the same problem.  [https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1393](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1393)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63440962

Answer (score 6):

The solution in my case (On MacOS), was to uninstall and reinstall dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator.

Run in terminal:

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator

dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.4
```

Comment: Worked for me on Windows!

Answer (score 6):

I have same problem when upgrade from .net core 3.1.4 to 5.0.1.

My solution:

1. update global tools:

```
  dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
  dotnet tool update --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
  dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
  dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

2. add/update links to packages

```
  dotnet remove package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
  dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
  dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

2. Replace string `netcoreapp3.1.4` to `net5.0` in .csproj and launch.json files
3. Clear directories

   - bin
   - obj
4. Rebuild project
5. Finally run:

```
  dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --help
```

If all fine it will show available generators.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this problem has been described in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1393#issuecomment-751526411) as the .NET code expecting a case-insensitive filesystem which fails on a Linux host.

A [suggested workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1393#issuecomment-752041418) would be to temporarily mount you `~/.nuget` directory on a vfat filesystem.

To do so create a dummy file holding the filesystem

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/mynuget bs=1024k count=2000
mkfs.vfat /tmp/mynuget
```

and then mount it

```
sudo mount -o uid=myuser,gid=myuser -t vfat /tmp/mynuget /home/myuser/.nuget
```

and use it

```
dotnet restore
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator ...
```

Comment: How would you do that on Mac OS?

Comment: @JonathanDaniel: To the best of my knowledge, this method should work on MacOS as well. But I have little to no experience on Apple devices.

Answer (score 0):

I test your command,and when I do this `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.4`,I can get
[image]

and then `Ran dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --help`,I get the same message  `No code generators are available in this project.Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet` with you,
but when I do the following,I can run without the message:
[image]

I think maybe the package is not added correctly,you can try to remove and add it again.

```
dotnet remove package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

Comment: I have tried the same. I guess you are using Windows. I have updated the OS I am using at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The newest versions are giving some problems, so you will have to **downgrade the version of the sdk to the 3.1.3** by writing this command on the terminal:

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-3.1=3.1.301-1
```

**After that you will need to install the following:**

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.3
```

**After that you will need to add the right Web.CodeGeneration.Design Package by writing this on the terminal:**

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-3.1=3.1.301-1
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.3
```