# Visual Studio 2022 is not finding codegenerators for scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Rel: [aspnet-codegenerator: No code generators available, Even after adding Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63584060/aspnet-codegenerator-no-code-generators-available-even-after-adding-microsoft)

I have the same issue as presented in the linked question but with Visual Studio 2022 and dotNet 6.
Scaffolding controller using *MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework* fails:
[image]
However *MVC Controller with read/write actions* succeeds.
But afterwards adding `view` for any of the actions likewise fails:
[image]

I have performed all actions suggested in the linked post. It looks like I have the right version:

`Tool 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '6.0.2').`

The list of available codegenerators looks to include everything:
[image]

**Update:** works from the command line though.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: What command line is this?

Comment: Found it...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-7.0